# Hiding Timeline on Task list causes full page refresh when calling manual refresh with JS

Tags: javascript, list-view, tasks

I am using JavaScript to programmatically call the `_doPostback` for a task listview webpart using this in my function:

```
setTimeout("__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl39$g_7fb81f26_0047_4c65_9ed0_0c625b5bb5d2$ctl05')",0);
```

This works great, but when I remove the Timeline from the view it stops doing the partial postback (webpart refresh only). Instead, a full page refresh happens.

The listview webpart is configured for manual refresh in the ajax settings in the webpart properties. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version this is for, but for 2013/O365 you can use the `AJAXRefreshView` function provided by SharePoint.

Example using the list title prop, you can use the property that suits you:

```
AJAXRefreshView({ 
    currentCtx: g_ctxDict[
                    Object.keys(g_ctxDict).filter(function(v) {
                        return "Tasks" === g_ctxDict[v].ListTitle
                    })
                ], 
    csrAjaxRefresh: true 
    }, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am using 2013 on-premise, the AJAXRefreshView is new to me. I am trying to implement this within a jquery selectmenu select function where I select a date range and three separate views of the same Tasks list will refresh asynchronously. The original way I was doing it using postback has to wait for each view to finish in turn. I have tried to implement your code to no avail. I am using it within onRequestSucceeded function to test